# Can we add border around the fontawesome icon using css?

Tags: css, icons, border

I need to change the border width of the icon - fa-comment-o. Can we change the border-width size with css?

Answer (score 107):

Yes you can. Use a text-shadow:

```
.my-icon {
     text-shadow: 0 0 3px #000;
}
```

Or Also you can use **webkit text stroke** remember it only work with **Chrome** and **Safari**

[CSS-Tricks example](https://css-tricks.com/adding-stroke-to-web-text/)

```
-webkit-text-fill-color: white;
-webkit-text-stroke-width: 1px;
-webkit-text-stroke-color: black;
```

Comment: Please upload your answer https://caniuse.com/#feat=text-stroke

Comment: This is for when you're using FA as a font. Many uses nowadays go with SVG, so this won't work.

Comment: Exact Answer for Fa Icons

Comment: @igorsantos07 But Question is For Fontawesome Icons, Not for SVG. So this is the best answer.

Comment: @AbijithAjayan I think you didn't read my comment correctly; most modern uses of FA icons are SVG-based, not font-based. I'm explaining that for SVG users which come here and get a bit confusing - they should use [@reiallenramos's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48618557/102960) instead.

Answer (score 39):

Use text-shadow property like following:

```
.my-bordered-icon{
  text-shadow: -1px 0 #000, 0 1px #000, 1px 0 #000, 0 -1px #000;
}
```

Answer (score 37):

As of v5.0.6, Font Awesome uses `svg`s and `path`s  to draw their icons. With a little help from the Inspect Element tool, here's how I put borders around the icon paths.

```
.fa-comment g g path {
  stroke: black;
  stroke-width: 10;
}
```

Comment: It wasn't clear for me how to make it work, so I created this test once I've made it work. To work in Chrome you have  to import the SVG version of font awesome.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Thank you.

Comment: It's advised to identify inside the SVG elements which one needs the stroke. In my case I wanted to add a border to fa-slash, and it's directly under `.fa-slash path`.

Answer (score 11):

It wasn't clear for me how to make it work, so I created this test once I've made it work. To work in Chrome you have to import the SVG version of font awesome (https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.8.1/js/all.js).

It works in chrome and firefox

```css
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  font-size: 10vw;
  background: #aaa;
}

.fa-times path {
  stroke: white;
  stroke-width: 30px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.8.1/js/all.js"></script>

<i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true"></i>
```

Answer (score 3):

Borders are built in - at least as of v4.6.

"Use fa-border and fa-pull-right or fa-pull-left for easy pull quotes or article icons."

```
    <i class="fa fa-camera-retro fa-border"></i> fa-lg
```

Padding, border style, color & more can be tweaked in the font-awesome css file; search for fa-border.

http://fontawesome.io/examples/#animated

Comment: This does not add the border around the icon itself, but the container.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by stacking other icons over the `fa-circle` icon to make them look circular in shape. Also the color can be inverted using the class `fa-inverse`.
You can place Font Awesome icons just about anywhere using the CSS Prefix `fa` and the icon's name. Font Awesome is designed to be used with inline elements (we like the `<i>` tag for brevity, but using a `<span>` is more semantically correct).

example and lear more abbout it http://fontawesome.io/examples/

To increase icon sizes relative to their container, use the fa-lg (33% increase), `fa-2x`, `fa-3x`, `fa-4x`, or `fa-5x` classes.

```
<i class="fa fa-camera-retro fa-lg"></i> fa-lg
<i class="fa fa-camera-retro fa-2x"></i> fa-2x
<i class="fa fa-camera-retro fa-3x"></i> fa-3x
<i class="fa fa-camera-retro fa-4x"></i> fa-4x
<i class="fa fa-camera-retro fa-5x"></i> fa-5x
```

Answer (score -1):

just give a class to your icon with following style.

```
.fa-border-icon {
    border-width: 3px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: orange;
    border-image: initial;
    border-radius: 50% 50% 50% 50%; 
    padding: 6% 9% 6% 9%; 
}
```

(use paddings and radius according to your need)

Answer (score -8):

**No,** you can't since it's part of the image.

You could however try and place something over it.