# Add border around font-awesome (v5) icon

Tags: css, font-awesome, font-awesome-5

This question has been asked before in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35933260/can-we-add-border-around-the-fontawesome-icon-using-css). But I don't think its still working with the new font-awesome because they use `svg` and `path` elements.

This question is about having a border around the icon, instead of having it around the outer circle.

---

**Some of the solutions found that I tried, but did not work:**

```css
.fa-female, .fa-music{
  color: #BBB;
}

.fa-female{
  -webkit-text-fill-color: #BBB;
  -webkit-text-stroke-width: 1px;
  -webkit-text-stroke:4px #00FF00;
}

.fa-music{
  text-shadow: 0px 0px 3px #00FF00;
}
```

```html
<script defer src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.6/js/all.js"></script>
 
<!-- Female Icon --> 
<span class="fa-layers fa-fw fa-8x" style="color: rgb(190, 53, 48)">
  <i class="fas fa-circle"></i>
  <i class="fas fa-female fa-inverse" data-fa-transform="shrink-6 fa-border"></i>
</span>

<!-- Music Icon --> 
<span class="fa-layers fa-fw fa-8x" style="color: rgb(190, 53, 48)">
   <i class="fas fa-circle"></i>
   <i class="fas fa-music fa-inverse" data-fa-transform="shrink-8 fa-border"></i>
</span>

<i class="fas fa-music fa-inverse fa-5x" style="color: black;"></i>
```

---

**Edit: Solution that worked in a codesnippet**
Solution by reiallenramos

```css
.fa-music g g path {
  stroke: black;
  stroke-width: 10;
}
```

```html
<script defer src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.6/js/all.js"></script>

<!-- Music Icon --> 
<span class="fa-layers fa-fw fa-8x" style="color: rgb(190, 53, 48)">
   <i class="fas fa-circle"></i>
   <i class="fas fa-music fa-inverse" data-fa-transform="shrink-8 fa-border"></i>
</span>
```

Comment: TL;DR try `fa-border`. Source: https://fontawesome.com/how-to-use/svg-with-js#bordered-pulled-icons

Comment: Yes and it doesnt work, I will add that to the code.

Comment: Ah I C, let me answer it for you.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I had to dissect the internals of font-awesome.

```
.fa-music g g path {
  stroke: black;
  stroke-width: 10;
}
```

Comment: Not around the circles but around the icons.

Comment: oh sorry. let me try again

Comment: Thank this worked! Awesome I was trying for almost over an hour. Ty

Comment: Happy to help :) Quick tip, use the Inspect Element tool in your browser. It gives you more insight and ideas on how to approach your problem

Comment: Ye I'm using that but I had no idea I could style the `path`

Answer (score 6):

The new FontAwesome way would be layers: https://fontawesome.com/how-to-use/svg-with-js#layering

```html
<script defer src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.6/js/all.js"></script>
 
<span class="fa-layers fa-fw fa-5x">
   <i class="fas fa-circle" style="color:black"></i>
   <i class="fas fa-circle" data-fa-transform="shrink-3" style="color:Tomato"></i>
   <i class="fa-inverse fas fa-female" data-fa-transform="shrink-6"></i>
</span>
```

Answer (score 3):

Please make stroke colour same as the icon background icon, then it will visible like the icon stroke is reduce.

Please try to use below style.

`-webkit-text-stroke:4px rgb(190, 53, 48)`

Answer (score -1):

I'm guessing you want a round border around the red icon?

You can add a new circle inside the layer span:

```
        <!-- Music Icon -->
    <span class="fa-layers fa-fw fa-8x fa-border" style="color: rgb(190, 53, 48)">
         <i class="fas fa-circle" style="color: black"></i>
        <i class="fas fa-circle" data-fa-transform="shrink-1"></i>
       <i class="fas fa-music fa-inverse" data-fa-transform="shrink-8"></i>
    </span>
```