# I am using an fa fa-star icon but i'm unable to make border on that fa star icon? How to do that?

Tags: html, css

I'm having problem in making borders over fa fa star icon. It works perfectly but it's displaying behind fa fa icon.

I tired putting it in i tag but still it's not working.

```html
<i class="fa fa-star" aria-hidden="true"></i>
<div class="text-block">
  <h4>Nature</h4>
  <p>What a beautiful sunrise</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Add your css code please, and if you have image of unexpected and expected result will be very helpful for other to help you.

Comment: .container {
      position: relative;
      }

/* Bottom right text */
    .text-block {
     position: absolute;
    bottom: 500px;
    right: 500px;
   background-color: black;
   color: white;
   padding-left: 20px;
   padding-right: 20px;
  display:block;
   }

  .icon{
 
   bottom: 500px;
         right: 700px;
 
         }

Comment: you css code does not have any property for setting `border`. You can learn how to set border from this tutorial. https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_border.asp

Comment: I do have a border class. Let me show it to you.

Comment: <section id="p16" class="padding">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row text-center">
    <div class="col-md-3 col-xs-6">
    <div class="MyPlan">
    <a href ="#p12" class="btn21" >LETS GET STARTED</a>
    <a href ="#p13" class="btn21"  style="background:#ffe46d" >MY 
     PROGRESS</a>
    </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-9 col-xs-6">
    <div class="border1">
    <h1 class="heading">Xxxxx xxxx Test1</h1>
    <div class="table-box"style="background:black; width:100%;margin- 
    top:20%;margin-left:0%;border:2px solid skyblue;display:block" >

Comment: <h2>You have completed the activity.</h2>
     <h2>Your Score: 76%</h2>
    </div>
    <i class="fa fa-star " aria-hidden="false" style="margin- 
    top:10%;color:#ffe46d; width:60%;height:60%;margin-top:-20%"></i>

   </div>
    </div>

    </div>
    </div>
   </section>

Comment: Please, see this code too.

Comment: P.s: Pardon me as I'm new to stackoverflow.

Comment: Put all relevant code in your question, not in the comments!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35933260/can-we-add-border-around-the-fontawesome-icon-using-css

Answer (score -1):

If you added the class `border` to your icon tag, you could then give the element a border by adding the following CSS to your project.

```
.border{
border: 1px solid #000;
}
```

If this is not what you are looking for, please update your question to be more descriptive about, in what way, you want to add a border to your element.