# How to remove the fill color(black) of smiley icon and change it to white

Tags: html, css, sass, fonts, icons

In my application I have a custom icon with black fill and now my requirement is to change the fill color to white and and border of the smiley will be black. And the smiley icon is given below

[image]

and my code is

```
<div>
<i class="icon icon-smiley-face-2"></i>
</div>
```

Now I want  the above smiley face as white filling background and border of the smiley would ne black.
Can anyone help me regarding the same

Answer (score 0):

See if this works or add a custom class on the i tag. If it is not working add an !important like below (only if it doesn't work without it)

```
.icon-smiley-face-2{
    stroke: #000000 !important; 
    fill: #ffffff !important;
  }
```

Comment: Thanks@Shiju Nambiar I have added the above styles in custom class ,but it is not working no change in the icons. Can you help me on this

Comment: What does this show on the DOM as?

Answer (score 0):

You can do that by simple CSS

```
.icon-smiley-face-2{
    color: #fff; 
    border:1px solid #000;
  }
```

Comment: In my smiley icon see the above the eyes are in white so if we change  the color to white entire icon will be turned to white(no icon will be shown)

Answer (score 0):

Check if it works. since it's your custom icon not sure how it's interact.

```
.icon-smiley-face-2{
   text-shadow: -1px 0 #000, 0 1px #000, 1px 0 #000, 0 -1px #000;
   color: white;
}
```

Reference - [stack ref for answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50270424/11168176)

Comment: thank you it is working fine but small thing is the eyes in the smiley icons are in like a circle but I need it as filled dot instead of round circle can you able to make it?

Comment: may be that's because of the design of your icon.

Comment: Ok, by using the above text shadow or some style can we able to fill the eyes color ?

Comment: I don't think so. since we aren't able to select the path of particular that part of the icon. If you can inspect thoroughly and select those path then it'll be possible.